# react-native-scrollable-tab-view Android issue #999

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollable-tab-view

I'm having the same issue as the one described at https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/999

I tried to apply the possible fix suggested there but with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! just pass the style to the scrollableTabView

style={{width: '100%' }}

Answer (score -1):

Solved it! Replace DefaultTabBar with ScrollableTabBar (don't forget to import it)